# Plesk/PHP Version per directory

Tags: php, windows, plesk

Need to have example.com/directory-1 and example.com/directory-2 run different versions of PHP.

Both versions are installed and working with plesk and I can switch between them and set different versions for subdomains or the entire domain but I need one directory to use an older version and everything else the newer one for backwards compatibility.

This is on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't seem to make any sense from an administration angle. What would/should happen if a script from directory-1 includes a script from directory-2 (or vice versa)? There will only be 1 interpreter and you can't switch between them while a script is run. So either work with subdomains or better yet, update your legacy scripts so you that everything works with the newer version of PHP.

Comment: While I understand the concern, they are completely independent applications and would never be calling each other.